# mongorestore not working. collection is empty

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

i am trying to dump a mongodb collection to file, and then use that to restore to another mongodb instance.

dumping -

```
mongodump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --username vespauser --password <passwd> --collection vespastats --db vespa --out /archive/vespa-archive/vespa-db-backup_001

    connected to: 127.0.0.1:27017
    2015-04-21T16:24:07.070-0400 DATABASE: vespa      to     /archive/vespa-archive/vespa-db-backup_testing01/vespa
    2015-04-21T16:24:07.141-0400    vespa.system.indexes to /archive/vespa-archive/vespa-db-backup_testing01/vespa/system.indexes.bson
    2015-04-21T16:24:07.148-0400             4 documents
    2015-04-21T16:24:07.149-0400    vespa.vespastats to /archive/vespa-archive/vespa-db-backup_testing01/vespa/vespastats.bson
    2015-04-21T16:24:07.316-0400             59724 documents
    2015-04-21T16:24:08.118-0400    Metadata for vespa.vespastats to /archive/vespa-archive/vespa-db-backup_testing01/vespa/vespastats.metadata.json
```

restoring -

```
mongorestore -v --drop --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --username admin --password <passwd> /archive/vespa-archive/vespa-db-backup_001

2015-04-21T16:31:11.962-0400 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
2015-04-21T16:31:11.963-0400 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2015-04-21T16:31:11.963-0400 connected to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1)
2015-04-21T16:31:11.963-0400 connected connection!
connected to: 127.0.0.1:27017
2015-04-21T16:31:11.966-0400 /home/amurty/vespa-db/vespa-db-backup_testing01/vespa/vespastats.bson
2015-04-21T16:31:11.966-0400    going into namespace [vespa.vespastats]
2015-04-21T16:31:11.966-0400     dropping
         file size: 88808161
59724 objects found
2015-04-21T16:31:13.730-0400    Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "vespa.vespastats" }
2015-04-21T16:31:13.848-0400    Creating index: { key: { url: 1 }, name: "url_1", ns: "vespa.vespastats", background: true }
2015-04-21T16:31:13.858-0400    Creating index: { key: { r_tstpm: 1 }, name: "r_tstpm_1", ns: "vespa.vespastats", background: true }
2015-04-21T16:31:13.859-0400    Creating index: { key: { url: 1, r_tstpm: 1 }, name: "url_1_r_tstpm_1", ns: "vespa.vespastats", background: true }
```

from /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log -

```
2015-04-21T16:31:11.963-0400 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58444 #23 (1 connection now open)
2015-04-21T16:31:11.964-0400 [conn23]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "admin", key: "xxx" }
2015-04-21T16:31:11.968-0400 [conn23] CMD: drop vespa.vespastats
2015-04-21T16:31:13.757-0400 [conn23] allocating new ns file /var/lib/mongo/vespa.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-21T16:31:13.838-0400 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongo/vespa.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-21T16:31:13.846-0400 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongo/vespa.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.007 secs
2015-04-21T16:31:13.847-0400 [conn23] build index on: vespa.vespastats properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "vespa.vespastats" }
2015-04-21T16:31:13.848-0400 [conn23]    added index to empty collection
2015-04-21T16:31:13.857-0400 [conn23] build index on: vespa.vespastats properties: { v: 1, key: { url: 1 }, name: "url_1", ns: "vespa.vespastats", background: true }
2015-04-21T16:31:13.857-0400 [conn23]    added index to empty collection
2015-04-21T16:31:13.858-0400 [conn23] build index on: vespa.vespastats properties: { v: 1, key: { r_tstpm: 1 }, name: "r_tstpm_1", ns: "vespa.vespastats", background: true }
2015-04-21T16:31:13.859-0400 [conn23]    added index to empty collection
2015-04-21T16:31:13.860-0400 [conn23] build index on: vespa.vespastats properties: { v: 1, key: { url: 1, r_tstpm: 1 }, name: "url_1_r_tstpm_1", ns: "vespa.vespastats", background: true }
2015-04-21T16:31:13.860-0400 [conn23]    added index to empty collection
2015-04-21T16:31:13.862-0400 [conn23] end connection 127.0.0.1:58444 (0 connections now open)
```

now when i login to my new mongodb instance and check collection size, i get a big 0 -

```
# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
connecting to: test
> use vespa
switched to db vespa
> db.auth('vespauser', '<paswd>')
1
> db.vespastats.find()
> db.vespastats.count()
0
>
```

Comment: Everything looks fine except the lack of docs...what's the count in the original collection (not gotten through the logs)?

Comment: more data was added to the original DB since i ran that, so the count now stands at - 60841. i obtained that count using db.collectionname.count()

Answer (score 0):

Collection may or may not exist in the **used** database but the query is not returning an error, just 0.

`db.vespastats.find().count()`

The issue should be because it is added to database **test**. (doc mentions it should be automatic but I was able to reproduce this behaviour).

Therefore

```
use test
db.vespastats.find().count()
```

would have returned the actual documents in the collection vespastats.
The issue is caused by not specifying db name when using mongo binary command `mongorestore`. [doc for mongorestore](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--db)  `mongorestore --nsInclude=vesta.vestastats` should be the updated version (even if -d still works).

To know where the collection would land, I would run 2 times the restore dump and check `show dbs` in mongo shell 3 times (before and after) > the db size is changing (not immediately though as it may show 8kb right after the restoration).